# React Native - run functions synchronously

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have written the following code, it **runs smoothly** but I have encountered a question:

```
submitFormToBackend = async () => {
  if (this.paymentMethod === 'apple-pay') {
    this.setState({ showLoadingIndicator: true }); // <-- below await setTimeout can confirm this line run before it
  }

  let requester = new ApplePayRequester({...this.form});
  let applePay = new ApplePay();

  await setTimeout(async () => {
    let cardTokenResponse = await applePay.getCardToken();
    if (cardTokenResponse.isSuccess()) {
      requester.setCardToken(cardTokenResponse.message);
      let response = await requester.pushToBackend();

      this.setState({ showLoadingIndicator: false }); //<-- below setTimeout can confirm this line run before them
      if (response.isSuccess()) {
        setTimeout(() => { this.navigator.backToPreviousScreen(); }, 800);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => { Alert.alert('your purchase has error. Try again'); }, 800);
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ showLoadingIndicator: false });
      setTimeout(() => { Alert.alert('cannot get your card token.'); }, 800);
    }
  }, 800);
};
```

My render() in that component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.form}>
      <LoadingIndicator visible={this.state.showLoadingShader} />

      <InputBox />
      <InputBox />

      <SubmitButton />
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you see there are a lot of `setTimeout()` functions, it seems like functions will crash together if I don't use `setTimeout()` to restrict the functions run one by one.

However, it's not a good practice as there is no default millisecond for success running (the millisecond can set to 700ms or 1500ms or etc.). Therefore I would like to ask is there any solution to confirm previous function has run before next function start, other than using `setTimeout()`?

---

**UPDATE**

[image]

Procedures:

**Step 1** - Press submit button
**Step 2** - Pop up a confirmation modal
**Step 3** - User confirm, dismiss confirmation modal, set `showLoadingIndicator` to `true` to show loading indicator
**Step 4** - Call ApplePay and pop up ApplePay UI
**Step 5** - User confirm, set `showLoadingIndicator` to `false` to dismiss loading indicator and navigate previous screen

---

**Problems encountered when not using `setTimeout()`:**

**Step 4** - ApplePay UI cannot pop up after setting `showLoadingIndicator` to `true`, below is the code that encountered problem:

```
 let cardTokenResponse = await applePay.getCardToken();
```

**Step 5** - Alert will be pop up before setting `showLoadingIndicator` to `false`, which stops the setting, below is the code that encountered problem:

```
  this.setState({ showLoadingIndicator: false });
  if (response.isSuccess()) {
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => { Alert.alert('your purchase has error. Try again'); }, 800);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A second optional parameter of `setState` function is a callback function that runs synchronously with the state change.

So you can just rely on the following:

```
this.setState({
  //change state variables here
}, () => {
   //do the next work here...
});
```

The callback function always run post the state is changed.

In your code, this would work:

```
this.setState({ showLoadingIndicator: false }, () => {
  if (response.isSuccess()) {
      this.navigator.backToPreviousScreen();
  } else {
   Alert.alert('your purchase has error. Try again');
  }
});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: _The setState callback fires regardless of what shouldComponentUpdate returns. So, the setState callback will fire, even when state hasn’t changed._

Comment: @suraj_malviya Thanks for your answer. I believe your answer is correct for callback after setState() function. However, it's still not working as using setTimeout(). I don't know why... :(

Comment: `it's still not working as using setTimeout()`, @WingChoy could you be more specific? Could you update your question adding this info, screenshots, the code you changed so we have more information on your issue please?

Comment: The alert comes out before the setState using the code you mentioned. One thing I would like to mention is my setState is used to control a react-native modal component visibility. Will this affect the result?